# Download images using HTML or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I need to download images from the server. In the below HTML5 code 'Download 1' downloads the image successfully. But 'Download 2' is navigating to the image URL instead of downloading the image. The main difference between 'Download 1' and 'Download 2' is 'Download 2' has file extension as'.jpg' in the file name. I want 'Download 2' to download the image.

I need to download images with the file extension. Please help to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance!

```html
<a id="download_image" href="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0jH18Lft7ypSmRjdWg1c082Y2M" download>Download 1</a>
<a id="download_image" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" download>Download 2</a>
```

Comment: On which browsers do you test that code?

Comment: what browser do you use? Because I tested this in chrome and they both worked perfectly for me

Comment: In Firefox there is an issue that file must come from your own server or domain name, otherwise it will be opened in the browser.

Comment: @mrdeadsven I am using Chrome version Version 67.0.3396.99. Download 2 link is navigating to the image not downloading

Comment: @SylwesterPilarz I am using chrome Version 67.0.3396.99

Comment: @ThangakumarD honestly no idea I even have an older version of chrome and it's working just fine both are getting downloaded like they should. Also a small thing not really relevant to the problem but try not to use the same id multiple times.

Answer (score 10):

Try the following using Promise and async/await :

```
toDataURL(url) {
    return fetch(url).then((response) => {
            return response.blob();
        }).then(blob => {
            return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        });
}
```

then

```
async download() {
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = await toDataURL("http://serverpath/images/50.jpg");
        a.download = "";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Find documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1):

I think it works :

```html
<HTML>
<Header></Header>

<body>
  <a id="download_image" href="" download="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0jH18Lft7ypSmRjdWg1c082Y2M">Download 1</a>
  <a id="download_image" href="" download="http://serverpath/images/50.jpg">Download 2</a>
</body>

</HTML>
```

and checkout online demo if you like https://codepen.io/zhipenglu/pen/dKQXQx

and here is another lib do the same thing called file-writer: https://github.com/azl397985856/file-writer

Comment: Both the links are downloading 0kb file, eventhough I use valid image URL

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine for me, maybe it will work for you if you try it like this by creating the link in javascript

```js
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.textContent = 'download image';

link.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    link.href = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg";
    link.download = "image.jpg";
}, false);

document.body.appendChild(link);
```

```html
<HTML>
<Header>
</Header>
<body>

</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Try this my code, using javascript and html`
    https://codepen.io/irfanzidan09/pen/XWWmYjN?editors=1111
dont forget add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a id="download_image" href="" download="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0jH18Lft7ypSmRjdWg1c082Y2M" download>Download 1</a>
```